# Remove text between specific tags and including those tags, in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

just a naive user, so excuse me for this silly question (by your standards ;))

Could you please guide me on how to remove text between two tags in notepad++, alongwith the tags surrounding it.

example:

```
<XXX:value key="YY">TEXT</XXX:value>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expresión.

- Use the remplace option (`Ctrl` + `H`) and select regular expresion as a search mode.

put this line in the `Find what:` text box.

> [^<>]+(?=[<])

The explanation of the regular expresion at next:

`[^<>]+` - Match a single character not present in the list below

`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`<>` matches a single character in the list <> (case sensitive)

`(?=[<])` - Positive Lookahead.
Assert that the Regex below matches

`[<]` Match a single character present in the list below

`<` matches the character < literally (case sensitive)

Comment: Thank you Fernando :). But as i said, am a naive user and dont understand much of this regular expressions. would you be able to guide me with the exact example i have put. so i can try to follow more clearly.

Comment: and the text YY is not constant...so i need a variable for that as well

Comment: Hi Guys, i have managed to crack it :)
<XXX:value key= ".*?">.*?</XXX>

Comment: @SatzN: Put it as an answer and accept it. It should be usefull for other people.

Comment: i supposed that the atribute `key=` will be diferent in all the document that you want to replace, thats why i gave you an example to replace text between any tag.

what do you want as a variable? the name of the tag? or whole the tag (open and close form)?